# What exactly does <system.codedom>/<compilers> do in web.config in MVC 5?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config, codedom

I am about to migrate a bunch of projects from .NET 4.0 + MVC 3 to .NET 4.5.2 + MVC5.

To make this easier, I've created a new blank MVC project to compare DLL references and some other stuff such as web.config.

In the latter, the following entries are generated by Visual Studio:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

But I don't know what this does exactly. The MVC 3 projects don't contain these parts. My understanding is it has something to do with Roslyn?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

These settings are used for [dynamic compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx). They can be safely removed from the web.config if you do pre-compilation and only put the compiled assemblies on the webserver.

See also [The impact of multiple compiler definitions in system.codedom in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713255/the-impact-of-multiple-compiler-definitions-in-system-codedom-in-web-config)

Comment: what happen if i remove it from the web.config in my server ?

Comment: @mejiamanuel57 your site will use the IIS app.config for all settings

Comment: Is Razor something that's compiled dynamically?

Comment: @Sheldortheconqueror This question (and this answer) only applies to `.aspx`/`.ascx` files used in ASP.NET WebForms. I believe that `System.CodeDom` is used by Razor in the earlier _non-ASP.NET Core_ version of ASP.NET MVC, but it's entirely irrelevant to ASP.NET Core and beyond which does not use `web.config`, and I believe modern Razor ("RazorV4" internally at MSFT) uses Roslyn directly without going through CodeDom (hence why VB.NET's `.vbhtml` is not supported by ASP.NET Core anymore).

Comment: @Sheldortheconqueror But in ASP.NET Core, Razor `.cshtml` files can be either precompiled (as part of a normal project build) or they can (still) be edited-and-compiled ("dynamic compilation" aka "runtime compilation") within a published website/web-application, but requires extra legwork (and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation`: see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation )

Answer (score 0):

These lines are added whenever you install `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform` nuget package.

It is for improved performance whether precompiling or dynamically compiling asp.net app, by using "Roslyn" compilation

In my case precompile went from 34mins to 13mins:

- [Dynamics CRM / Any ASP.NET App - Improve C# dynamic compilation times](https://dev.to/janisveinbergs/dynamics-crm-improve-58g9)
- [How to speed up aspnet_compiler.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342126/50173)
- [Enabling the .NET Compiler Platform (“Roslyn”) in ASP.NET applications.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/enabling-the-net-compiler-platform-roslyn-in-asp-net-applications/)