# Is CodeDom required by a deployed web application?

Tags: asp.net

Is CodeDom needed for anything in a deployed application? Can the `<system.codedom>` section be safely removed from Web.config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's got to do with dynamic compilation in a multi-language environment. If you're not using more than one language, then you don't need it:

[The impact of multiple compiler definitions in system.codedom in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713255/the-impact-of-multiple-compiler-definitions-in-system-codedom-in-web-config)

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/dynamically-creating-applications-using-system-codedom/